# Why all applets of a package are not installed? And why I can't delete them?

Tags: smartcard, javacard

This is contents of my JavaCard :

```
GP::: gp -list
AID: A000000151000000 (|....Q...|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected,
 CVM (PIN) management

AID: A0000001515350 (|....QSP|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     A000000151535041 (|....QSPA|)
```

In *Eclipse* I add 3 applets to a single package as below :

- Pack AID = 01020304050607080900

  - App1 AID = 0102030405060708090000
  - App2 AID = 0102030405060708090001
  - App3 AID = 0102030405060708090002

**Step1:**

I converted this package to a *.cap* file and installed it successfully on my card using *JCManager*.

When I list the applets using *gp*, it returns :

```
GP::: gp -list
AID: A000000151000000 (|....Q...|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected,
 CVM (PIN) management

AID: 0102030405060708090002 (|...........|)
     App SELECTABLE: (none)

AID: A0000001515350 (|....QSP|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     A000000151535041 (|....QSPA|)

AID: 01020304050607080900 (|..........|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     0102030405060708090002 (|...........|)
     0102030405060708090001 (|...........|)
     0102030405060708090000 (|...........|)
```

**Step2:**

I want to delete App1 and App2 :

```
GP::: gp -delete 0102030405060708090000
Could not delete AID (not present on card): 0102030405060708090000

GP::: gp -delete 0102030405060708090000 -deletedeps
Could not delete AID (not present on card): 0102030405060708090000

GP::: gp -delete 0102030405060708090001
Could not delete AID (not present on card): 0102030405060708090001

GP::: gp -delete 0102030405060708090001 -deletedeps
Could not delete AID (not present on card): 0102030405060708090001
```

But for App3 I have a different output :

```
GP::: gp -delete 0102030405060708090002 -deletedeps
Could not delete AID: 0102030405060708090002
openkms.gp.GPException: Deletion failed SW: 6A88
        at openkms.gp.GlobalPlatform.check(GlobalPlatform.java:924)
        at openkms.gp.GlobalPlatform.deleteAID(GlobalPlatform.java:739)
        at openkms.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:291)
```

Note that I can delete App3 without parameter `-deletedeps` successfully :

```
GP::: gp -delete 0102030405060708090002   

GP:::
```

And when I want to delete the package, I must add `deletedeps` :

```
GP::: gp -delete 01020304050607080900
Could not delete AID: 01020304050607080900
TIP: Maybe try with --deletedeps
openkms.gp.GPException: Deletion failed SW: 6985
        at openkms.gp.GlobalPlatform.check(GlobalPlatform.java:924)
        at openkms.gp.GlobalPlatform.deleteAID(GlobalPlatform.java:739)
        at openkms.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:291)

GP::: gp -delete 01020304050607080900 -deletedeps

GP:::
```

**Question of Step1 :**

**Q1:** Why there is not AID of APP1 and APP2 as an applet like APP3 in the output?
(In the other word why I see APP1 and APP2 AIDs in subset of the Package, But I can the as a Applet installed on the card?)  Are they installed or not?

**Question of Step2 :**

**Q2:** Why I can't delete App1 and App2?

**Q3:** What is the meaning of the error[`6A88`] in deleting App3 with parameter `-deletedeps`? Why I receive it?

**Q4:** When I must use `deletedeps` and when I don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a single applet *installed*:

`AID: 0102030405060708090002 (|...........|)
     App SELECTABLE: (none)`

And you have a package with 3 applets *loaded*:

`AID: 01020304050607080900 (|..........|)
     ExM LOADED: (none)
     0102030405060708090002 (|...........|)
     0102030405060708090001 (|...........|)
     0102030405060708090000 (|...........|)`

You can only delete one existing applet 0102030405060708090002 and you can't delete the package  01020304050607080900 without either deleting the active instance 0102030405060708090002 first or by using `-deletedeps` which also deletes the installed applet.

Comment: Thank you. But may I ask you to explain more complete? How I can install the two other applets? I tried `-install` parameter for the same _.cap_ file in **gp**, but nothing changed! It only installed APP3 just like **JCManager**. I also tried `-instance` parameter with AID of APP1/APP2, but nothing changed agian! What is this `instance` parameter for?

Comment: `gp -create <instance aid> -package <packageaid> -applet <appletaid>`.

Instance AID you choose, package AID and applet AID come from the `ExM`. 

`-instance` was an unused parameter which is now removed from code.

Comment: Why they are not installed automatically just like app3? and why app3 installed? What make **gp** to prefer App3 for installing? And, last question: is it possible to remove an applet from a package? for example I want to delete App1, is it possible?

Comment: You need to update gp from Git. And: automatic installation only works if the package has single applet. Otherwise --create needs to be used. And you can't delete an applet (executable aid) from loaded package.

Comment: Thank you. I'll update it. Excuse me, Are _Installing_ and creating _instaces_ equal? or it is different and we have 3 steps to make an applet usable. (I mean uploading-installing-creating instace)

Comment: In the other word, can I say "In the question, I uploaded and installed App1,App2 and App3. But I make instance only for App3"? Or I must say "I uploaded all applets, But I installed only App3"?

Comment: Dear Martin, I eagerly waiting for the answer for my last comments.

Comment: `-install` is a shorthand for `-load applet.cap` and `-create instanceaid`.

Comment: "I can't delete packages wit active instances. and I must delete the instances first." OK. Is there any similar situation for applets? I mean, is there any state that I can't delete an applet? and I must delete it dependencies first? Or I can delete any applet instance whenever that I want?